# Get NSScreen with the keyboard focus on sandbox

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, accessibility, appstore-sandbox

What I want to know is which `NSScreen` has keyboard focus.

First I added an observer for `NSWorkspace.didActiveApplicationNotification` and whenever `foo` method is called I need to determine which `NSScreen` has keyboard focus.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(foo), name: NSWorkspace.didActivateApplicationNotification, object: nil)
```

All I have from this notification is `NSRunningApplication` object, but it doesn't tell me which screen is focused.

In [NSScreen documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen) I found [main property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388371-main) of NSScreen with description

> Returns the screen object containing the window with the keyboard
>   focus.

It's exactly what I want, but it doesn't work as I thought. It returns the wrong screen. In the header file, I found this information

> // cached value, possibly stale

I tried Accessibility, everything was OK, but it doesn't work when Sandbox is enabled so I can't use it.

Does anybody have any idea how to get NSScreen object with keyboard focus?

Comment: "It doesn't work as I thought", "It returns wrong screen"; I think you need to be more specific about what's going wrong. Screens don't have keyboard focus, windows do - and the window can e.g. be on multiple screens at once.

Comment: @TheNextman, because property is cached, reading `NSScreen.main` after `foo` method call will occur with stale value. After few miliseconds value is correct, but I need it immediately without any delay.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't get a better solution. You need to determine the key window; and if it's not your application, and you can't use accessibility, I think you're SOL.

Comment: Have you tried the API of `Quartz Display Services` mentioned in the documentation of `NSScreen`?

Comment: @mschmidt Yes, I have tried, but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: you can include the NSScreen when the notification is triggered if you append it to the notification's user info dic. Then in your foo selector take the notification as an argument